# IE8 - how to reopen tabs in all windows after a restart?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

In Firefox, if I have multiple windows open with several tabs each, all will be reopened when I restart FF.

In IE8. If I restart and click "Reopen last browsing session", IE reopens tabs from only one of the windows. Is there a way to make it reopen tabs from all windows?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T???

Answer (score 1):

I have IE 8.0.6001.18813 and mine restores both windows and tabs. Try the following:

1. Open two windows of IE8 (one should already be open as you are reading this ).
2. Open multiple tabs on each window using different sites for each tab.
3. Open Task Manager (read the following prior to performing the step)
4. On the Application Tab right-click and end task on one of your IE windows.

   (Make sure you do not click on the close dialog for IE. Just end task again.)
5. This should kill both your IE windows.
6. Reopen IE and you should get the restore session dialog.
7. Click restore and both windows and tabs should be restored.

Comment: The restart may actually be closing IE. This process will only recover due to a crash. I think reopen last session pertains to the last tab in use. BTW if you look in task manager you will notice each tab runs under its own process though IE8 manages all. If you kill one process you will see the tab recover

Answer (score 0):

Try [IE7pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/) addon for this:

> IE7Pro is a must have add-on for Internet Explorer, which includes a
>   lot of features and tweaks to make your IE friendlier, more useful,
>   secure and customizable. IE7Pro includes Tabbed Browsing Management,
>   Spell Check, Inline Search, Super Drag Drop, Crash Recovery, Proxy
>   Switcher, Mouse Gesture, Tab History Browser, Web Accelerator, User
>   Agent Switcher, Webpage Capturer, AD Blocker, Flash Block,
>   Greasemonkey like User Scripts platform, User Plug-ins, MiniDM, Google
>   sponsored search,IE Faster and many more power packed features. You
>   can customize not just Internet Explorer, but even your favorite
>   website according to your need and taste using IE7Pro.

Comment: Last time I tried IE7Pro with IE8 (about a month ago), I started having frequent crashes in IE. I'd stay away from this add on until they fix some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is possible, since each Internet Explorer window is a separate process (unlike FF) only the settings of the last closed window can be reused.

however, the registered version of [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) allows for multiple sandboxes and if you open each IE window in a different sandbox then it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If I open several windows of FF, with several tabs in each, only the last closed windows tab-set is opened the next time I open FF. However, IE8 lets me reopen last browser session. If I have a large tab-set that I wish to work on at a later point in time, I add the entire set to Favorites using "Add current tabs to Favorites", under it's own folder, and name the folder something relevant.. That way I'm sure to keep all my tabs for later... There's no limit to the number of Favorites your browser can handle.. ;o)